# How do I make a function update dynamically when I make changes to the function in a "master" cell?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

For example, column 1 would contain input data, and subsequent columns would perform actions on that data.

Row 1 would be the master row.  All changes to the formulas in row 1 would be duplicated down the sheet automatically when changes are made to the master.

I know I can select the row and drag it down to do this (or CTRL+Enter), but I'd like it to happen automatically.  I have various kinds of input data and I'm working to develop a set of functions that work for all of them without error, and replicating the functions down the column after each time is getting tedious.

Comment: A table can do this automatically for you.  You may not need all the extra functionality a table provides but it will cascade a formula down a column for you.

Comment: That's a good answer... I wonder what it is about tables that allows this.  Like, how do they achieve it in the background?

It'd be nice to have the formula visible in the top row and editable there with the actual calculations showing below.